# Get the current size of an account in anchor

Tags: anchor

If I have an account that's passed into my anchor program, I can get its bump by doing

`let acc_bump = ctx.bumps(ctx.accounts.my_account);`

Is there something equivalent if I want to know the current size of an account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some variation of the following snippets to get the byte length of an account passed into an instruction

```
let acc_info = ctx.accounts.my_account.to_account_info().data_len(); // will return a usize
```

```
let account = ctx.accounts.my_account.clone().into_inner();

let account_size = (account.try_to_vec()?).len(); // will return a usize
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks!